# utorrent does not work with proxy server

Tags: networking, windows-8, proxy, utorrent

I have utorrent 3.2.2(build 28500) 32-bit. I am trying to download torrent using a proxy server but nothing is working. It shows that you have a wrong network configuration. But the same server settings is working for Google chrome and Internet Download Manager. How to do it ?

[image]
Also one questions:

Any way to convert torrent to direct download other than zbigz.com, torrific.com and torcache.com ( i tried them, not working)?

Answer (score 2):

Try to "use proxy for peer-to-peer connections" and DNS/hostnames lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the ports are blocked by your proxy server. For example, the proxy server in our university keeps only port 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) open so even though Chrome, IDM and such stuff work, torrents don't because the port is blocked. If you could do tunnelling or something, they would but I am not aware how to tunnel in Windows.